# I can neither see Ubuntu partition in Windows disk management nor boot to enter Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning

I wrote a code that copies a file to a certain destination. However, I forgot to add a line that stops the iteration where copying takes place. Hence, the copy of the file gets bigger and bigger and eventually, my system crashed. Now, I cannot boot Ubuntu but can Windows and cannot see the partition that is related to my Ubuntu environment.
What can I do about this problem? Do I need to format Ubuntu and reinstall it?

Comment: The question is totally unclear. You did something, now you can't boot. It is not answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a live session of Ubuntu from a USB device like the one you used to install Ubuntu. Choose the option "try Ubuntu without installing".

Then, mount the drive or partition that contains the repeated files and delete the copied files manually.

You cannot see the partition from Windows because Windows doesn't support the EXT4 filesystem used for Ubuntu by default.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I used the boot manager to enter Ubuntu recovery and freed some small space from there like 450 kB. Then, my system opens without any problem. Thanks again!